# Load data from CSV file for load testing and keep session for each user

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I would like to log in an application with multiple users(each of who has an active session when logged in) and do stuff. Instead of logging them in, one by one in seperate thread groups, would it be possible to load e.g. 20 users from a CSV file(with each having a unique session) in one thread group?

I log each user in a seperate thread group, yet i would like to automate things a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can (actually you should — thats how [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) works) use one thread group to simulate concurrent users.
Set "Number of Threads (users)" to e.g. 20.

In addition you may read the [Guide to JMeter Thread Groups](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/05/guide-jmeter-thread-groups/) to get more information.

Comment: I have successfully created the scenario for one user. But for many users, if i set the Number of Threads,it will only repeat loop through my scenario and not create a unique session (through cookies) for each user that has to login, as far as i am concerned.

Comment: Could you write a structure of your project?

Comment: It turns out that by using a CSV Data Set Config and the appropriate parameters in it, i had the desired result. Also by adjusting the Number of Threads (users), i controlled how many users of my CSV file will log in.